# Sorting Complex object Structure with values using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have a complex object which looks like below.

```js
{
  "PartNumber": "A123456",
  "Components": [{
      "Part": {
        "Number": "123"
      },
      "Components": []
    },
    {
      "Part": {

        "Number": "300"
      },
      "Components": [{
          "Part": {
            "Number": "444"
          },
          "Components": [{
              "Part": {
                "Number": "A123"
              },
              "Components": [{
                "Part": {

                  "Number": "1234"
                }
              }]
            },
            {
              "Part": {
                "Number": "443"
              },
              "Components": []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "Part": {
            "Number": "H123"
          },
          "Components": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Part": {
        "Number": "120"
      },
      "Components": []
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to Sort the object using the values of **Number** key. I have tried using different sort functions and those were not working for my complex object.

Can someone help in achieving the sort of Complex objectusing JavaScript?
The object when simplified will be like

```
A123456             
    123         
    300         
        444     
            A123    
                1234
            443 
        H123        
    120
```

I need to sort the object and the expected simplified object output will be

```
A123456             
    120         
    123         
    300         
        444     
            443 
            A123    
                1234
        H123
```

Comment: [There is no such thing as a JSON](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+sort+nested+object+value+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor. I made you such a snippet. Please add the script you tried

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const sortedComponents = Components.sort(
  (component1, component2) => component1.Part.Number - component2.Part.Number
);
```

I think this solves your problem.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.